# stunnel No certificate returned unknown CA

Tags: authentication, ssl, configuration, openssl, stunnel

I have 2x stunnels linux based, 1 server, 1 client.
What I am trying to do is to use a stunnel client and with verify 3 it authenticates the user based on the certificate.

Here are the config files of each:

Client:

```
cert = /stunnel/client_Access_stunnel.pem
key = /stunnel/client_Access_stunnel.pem
CAfile = /stunnel/client_Access_stunnel.pem
CApath = /stunnel/cacerts/

flips=no
pid    = /var/run/stunnel-tcap.pid

; Socket parameters tuning
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:SO_KEEPALIVE=1
socket = r:SO_KEEPALIVE=1

output = /stunnel/stunnel.log
client = yes
;verify = 3
debug = 5
[tcap]
accept = 0.0.0.0:3701
connect = 192.168.1.4:3700
```

Server:

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel/server.pid

cert = /opt/quasar/cert/certs/stunnels/server.pem
key = /opt/quasar/cert/certs/stunnels/server.pem

CApath = /opt/certs/stunnels/cacerts/

; Socket parameters tuning
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:SO_KEEPALIVE=1
socket = r:SO_KEEPALIVE=1

; Security level
verify = 2

; Uncomment for troubleshooting purposes
debug = 7


; Log file path
output = /opt/stunnels/stunnel.log

[stunnel1]
accept = 0.0.0.0:3700
connect = 127.0.0.1:3701
```

The error is:

Client:

```
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG7[77]: Remote descriptor (FD=11) initialized
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[77]: SNI: sending servername: 192.168.104.74
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG7[77]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG7[77]: SSL state (connect): SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[78]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[78]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[78]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[77]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[77]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG6[77]: Certificate verification disabled
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG7[77]: SSL alert (read): fatal: unknown CA
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG3[77]: SSL_connect: 14094418: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG5[77]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2016.11.16 12:55:10 LOG7[77]: Deallocating application specific data for addr index
```

Server:

```
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate request A
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 flush data
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG4[36384:140097622492928]: VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=UK/ST=London/L=London/O=org/OU=OP/CN=client/emailAddress=operations@n.se
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG7[36384:140097622492928]: SSL alert (write): fatal: unknown CA
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG3[36384:140097622492928]: SSL_accept: 140890B2: error:140890B2:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
2016.11.16 11:55:17 LOG5[36384:140097622492928]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
```

Please ignore the time-stamps. same error different times.

- I have added the CA certificate to the client_Access_stunnel.pem,
  unchanged.
- I have added all CA's certs in to CApath
- cert was signed by xca locally managed

Comment: How did you put the CA into CApath? Did you used the filename based on the subject hash or just some other name? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396048/openssl-certificate-verification-fails-when-capath-argument-is-used-in-ssl-ctx

Comment: Hello Steffen! Thanks for you reply, I have named all the ca files with their hash.0 as advised but did it without the use of c_rehash I ran the command on top of the current ones and it linked 2 to a crt I had in that folder. But it seems to have not made a difference. The error is still the same. SSL_connect: 14094418: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

Comment: That I did it manually could that be the cause to this not working?

Comment: just used: openssl x509 -in <CA file name> -noout -subject_hash and it all looks correct.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)